# Не меняется кодировка(Collation) в столбце MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

пытаюсь сделать столбец регистрозависимым путем смены Collation на utf8_bin.Но после выполнения скрипта ничего не меняется и столбец остается  table default.

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable`.`user` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `user_login` `user_login` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL COMMENT 'логин' ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так Вы Collation меняйте:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` CHANGE `your_column` your_field_column_type CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

На всякий случай, для таблицы:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

И всей базы:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```